# I cannot get into nested JSON object, but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch data from an API (the Magic the Gathring Scryfall API) that has a nested object while using ReactJS. As soon as I try to use data from a nested object, I get a "cannot read png of undefined". I figured out this was probably an async problem, and fixed it by changing the state of my initial array to null, then adding an if statement to the render, but as soon as I changed the API url from https://api.scryfall.com/cards?page=3 to https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=cmc&q=c%3Ared+pow%3D3, I can no longer access the image urls in the nested object again, despite having a JSON in the same format returned to me as the first URL. I'm just at a loss now.

I tried using axios, and I tried putting the fetch into a separate function, then putting that function into componentDidMount, but no luck. Setting 'cards' to null and then putting the "if (cards === null) { return null; } into the render worked for the first link, but not the second.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {

    super()

    this.state = {

      cards: null,
      isUpdated:false

      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateCards()
  }

  populateCards() {
    let url = 'https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=cmc&q=c%3Ared+pow%3D3 '
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log("setting the state.")
        console.log(json.data)
      this.setState({cards: json.data})
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    if (cards === null) {
      return null;
    }
    let cards1 = this.state.cards
    let cardItems = cards1.map((card) => {

      return (
        <li>{card.name} - {card.id}
        <p></p><img src={card.image_uris.png}/></li>
      )
    })

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
        <Login />
        <ul>
        {cardItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Just need to figure out what is going on with this JSON before I can move on to writing up some search boxes. Greatly appreciate any help that can be offered.

The JSON coming back looks like so:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "total_cards": 248583,
  "has_more": true,
  "next_page": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards?page=4",
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "card",
      "id": "18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1",
      "oracle_id": "a6543f71-0326-4e1f-b58f-9ce325d5d036",
      "multiverse_ids": [
        463813
      ],
      "name": "Gateway Plaza",
      "printed_name": "門前廣場",
      "lang": "zht",
      "released_at": "2019-05-03",
      "uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1",
      "scryfall_uri": "https://scryfall.com/card/war/246/zht/%E9%96%80%E5%89%8D%E5%BB%A3%E5%A0%B4?utm_source=api",
      "layout": "normal",
      "highres_image": false,
      "image_uris": {
        "small": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/small/front/1/8/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1.jpg?1556241680",
        "normal": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/normal/front/1/8/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1.jpg?1556241680",
        "large": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/large/front/1/8/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1.jpg?1556241680",
        "png": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/png/front/1/8/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1.png?1556241680",
        "art_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/art_crop/front/1/8/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1.jpg?1556241680",
        "border_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/border_crop/front/1/8/18794d78-5aae-42de-a45b-3289624689f1.jpg?1556241680"
       },
      "mana_cost": "",
      "cmc": 0,
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, well done on a nicely formatted first question! First off, is your console.log in the fetch returning that data above? Have you tried logging json.data.image_uris from here?

Comment: Secondly, personally I prefer to use a loose comparison of null on javascript, as `== null` will match `null` AND `undefined`

Comment: `json.data[0].image_uris` *^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some object on your response does not have the `image_uris` property so it throw error.

Add these line

```
let filtered = cards1.filter(card => card.image_uris);
```

And then map over filtered array, you will get what you need

```
let cardItems = filtered.map(card => {
  return (
    <li>
      <img src={card.image_uris.png}/>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Comment: This fixed the issue! Thank you so much! I will have to find out if getting rid of the cards without image_uris will be an issue, but that's a different issue, at least now I know what was causing the problem.